# What does fileset actually do?

Tags: gradle, ant

```
ant.path(id: 'cobertura.classpath.id') {
    fileset(dir: 'cobertura', includes: '**/*.txt', excludes: '**/*.java')
```

I know it groups all the files that includes .txt and excludes all.java in the cobertura directory.

My question is; if I run the task is it suppose to create a folder, zip file or something? When it gets (grouped).

[My Reference](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fileset` doesn't do anything. It's just, as it's name indicates, a set of files. So, the above code defines a `path` variable, whose id is `'cobertura.classpath.id'`, and which contains all .txt files in the directory named cobertura.

I guess some other task in the build file uses this path.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying,I tried sending it to a destination, and the files did not comply. using destionationDir ()